# Avoid folder deletion from code

Tags: c#, directory

I am locking a folder by appending `".{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}"` to the folder name through my C# code.

The location of new folder name with the appended text to it is being saved in a variable `new_dir`.

My code appends data inside a `.txt` file in this folder. Now I want to avoid this folder from being deleted by any user even an administrator. Windows allows this by changing group policies, but I do not want that.

I came up with the idea of opening a file in that folder and keeping it open so that the folder doesn't get deleted, but I am unable to implement it.

Can anyone help me out with how to implement this concept in my program?

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\Foldertest\SomeTextFile.txt"))
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

The file is open in the `using`-statement and the folder or a parent folder can't be deleted. As soon as it is exited the stream will be closed and the file/folder can be deleted. So it's up to you what you do in the `using`.

Comment: thanks tim but i am using a windows form and locking the folder on button click so after the form exits will i be able to still prevent the folder from deleting

Comment: @NishantDwivedi: why a winforms application? Much better would be a windows service

Comment: i have less knowledge working with windows service....but what i asked...would that be possible????

Comment: @NishantDwivedi: theoretically, but then the application must not be exited or ended via task manager. Look at my edited version. You can even hide the form without ending the application.

Comment: public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       
 {

            dir = @"D:\" + textBoxData.Text;
            new_dir = dir + for_lock;
            
            pwd();
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\" + new_dir + @"\data.txt"))   <------- (getting error here)
            {
                Application.Run(new Form2());
            }
            //Monitor.Exit(new_dir);
        }


The error says An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll